# smooth-scrolling on second click with data-toggle

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, twitter-bootstrap, smooth-scrolling

My smooth scroll wont execute correctly. I have several tab menys with content in them and when I click a tab0 I want the smooth scroll to scroll down to the conent area. I have sevral conent areas.But nothing happens on the first click, but on the second click the scoll executes. The data-toggle gets all messed up also. It loses track of the tab with the `active` class on it. I am using Bootstraps `data-toggle`to switch between tab content. The tabs and smooth scroll apperantly wont co-exist. I have banged my head bloody on this problem for awhile. What am I doing wrong? This is my code.

> JS code

```
  $(document).ready(function(){

  $(".tabs a").on('click', function(event) {

    // Make sure this.hash has a value before overriding default behavior
    if (this.hash !== "") {

      event.preventDefault();

      var hash = this.hash;

      $('html, body').animate({
        scrollTop: $(hash).offset().top
      }, 1000, function(){

        window.location.hash = hash;
      });
    } 
  });
});
```

> HTML code: tab links

```
    <div class="tabs">
        <ul id="myTabContent" class="nav nav-tabs">
            <li class="active"><a href="#Hem" data-toggle="tab">Hem</a></li>
            <li class=""><a href="#Historia" data-toggle="tab">Historia</a></li>
            <li class=""><a  href="#Ridlärarna" data-toggle="tab">Ridlärare</a></li>

            <!--<li class=""><a href="#tab5" data-toggle="tab">Avbokning och igenridning</a></li>-->
        </ul>
```

> HTML code: tab-content

```
<div id="myTabContent" class="tab-content">

                        <div class="tab-pane fade active in" id="Hem">
                            <div class="media">

                                <div class="media-body">
                                    <h1 class="media-heading ruler-bottom">Hem</h1>
                                    <p class="diffrentFont">Text...</p>
                                                            </div>
                            </div>
                    </div>

                    <div class="tab-pane fade" id="Historia">
                        <div class="media">
                            <img src="images/firstpage.jpg" class="spacing-r imgRadius ResponsiveImgWidth" alt="">
                            <div class="media-body">
                                <h1 class="media-heading ruler-bottom">Historia</h1>
                                <p class="diffrentFont">Text...</p>

                            </div>
                        </div>

                    </div>
                    <div class="tab-pane fade" id="Ridlärarna">
                        <div class="media">
                            <img src="images/Ridlärare/Sample.jpg" class="spacing-r imgRadius customlärare" alt="">
                            <img src="images/Ridlärare/Sample.jpg" class="spacing-r imgRadius customlärare" alt="">
                            <div class="media-body">
                                <h1 class="media-heading ruler-bottom">Ridlärare</h1>
                                <p class="diffrentFont">Text...</p>

                            </div>
                        </div>
                    </div>
```

Comment: Your data-toggle gets messed up because your divs are not proper. Especially for the first tab.

Comment: Do you mean the p tag that didn't have a proper end tag?  Fix it. Anything else you can spot?

Comment: First tab has missing </div>s.. Copy paste this for the first tab -                         <div class="tab-pane fade active in" id="Hem">
                            <div class="media">
                                <div class="media-body">
                                    <h1 class="media-heading ruler-bottom">Hem</h1>
                                    <p class="diffrentFont">Text...<div class="readmore">
                                    </div>
                            </div>
                            </div>
                        </div>

Comment: Used your code. The scroll still happens on second click.